# Replace images in PhotoSwipe gallery

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I have a [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) gallery on my page which is created programatically like this:

```
var instance = window.Code.PhotoSwipe.attach(image, options)
```

Now I want to update the images in the gallery, or put a new gallery in the same spot.

Creating a new gallery for the same `DOM Element` omits the following error:

```
Code.PhotoSwipe.activateInstance:
Unable to active instance as another instance is already active for this target
```

Detaching the instance from the Element using `Code.PhotoSwipe.detatch(instance)` didn't help either.

Any ideas how to fill the gallery with new images, or remove it, so I can create a new one in the same place?

Comment: Hello, I want to do exactly this. I want it to refresh the gallery when the user swipes to the next image because an image gets added to the DOM on swipe. I am struggling to do it! Did you manage to do it in the end? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the very same problem. Want to update the gallery and switch out some images after it has been initialized. Did any of you ever figure this out? I can't detach and re-create the instance because that would be visible to the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I found to avoid that error was calling `unsetActivateInstance` before `detatch`:

```
window.Code.PhotoSwipe.unsetActivateInstance(instance);

window.Code.PhotoSwipe.detatch(instance);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also hide the current active instance, instead of detatching it by calling

```
window.Code.PhotoSwipe.activeInstances[0].instance.hide(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above but none of them worked well.

So my solution was to simply never create the gallery for the same ID twice:

```
    instance = window.Code.PhotoSwipe.getInstance(myuniqueid);
    if (window.Code.Util.isNothing(instance)) {
        // Only initialize if there is no gallery with this ID already.
        myPhotoSwipe = window.Code.PhotoSwipe.attach(window.document.querySelectorAll(galleryimagesselector), {captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, jQueryMobile: true, preventSlideshow: true, enableMouseWheel: false, enableKeyboard: false}, myuniqueid);
    }
```